# Type Observable<Customer | undefined> is not assigneable to type Observable<Customer>

Tags: angular, typescript

On the latest Angular 12, I am getting error:

Type Observable<Customer | undefined> is not assignable to type Observable

Beside using Observable, what is the new typescript way to handling this?
Prefer to avoid using 'any'

inside my ngOnInit() {
const customer = Observable = this.store.select(myCustomerReducer.getCurrentCustomer)
}

I tried const customer = Observable = this.store.select(myCustomerReducer.getCurrentCustomer) ?? new Observable();

but that did not work.

In the myCustomerReducer code

```
const getCustomerFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<CustomerState>(
    "customers"
)
export const getCurrentCustomerId = createSelector(
  getCustomerFeatureState,
  (state: CustomerState) => state.selectedCustomerId
);
export const getCurrentCustomer = createSelector(
  getCustomerFeatureState,
  getCurrentCustomerId,
  state => state.entities[state.selectedCustomerId ?? 0]
);
```

I had to add ?? 0 to remove the error that state.selectedCustomerId cannot be null as an index type

In Angular 11, this builds, but stuck on how to fix this issue.

I also tried moving the

```
const customer = Observable<Customer> = new Observable<Customer>();
```

as a class but when I assigned it the following, same error showed up again.

```
 this.customer = this.store.select(myCustomerReducer.getCurrentCustomer) ?? new Observable<Customer>();
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide additional details.  What is `this.store`?  How is `myCustomerReducer.getCurrentCustomer` defined?

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean to be using ":" instead of "=" to set the types?

```
const customer: Observable<Customer> = new Observable<Customer>();
```